# IBM MQ queue - Configuring a particular JVM

Tags: jvm, ibm-mq, mq

We have a queue manager and using IBM webspehere connection is made using listener to the queue.

I want to restrict the messages based on some parameter to particular JVM. I have twp JVMs. So some messages should go to first JVM and rest should go to second JVM.

Can anyone help me to know how this can be achieved?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Either have a queue per application (JVM) or have a correlation ID per application (JVM) on the same queue, then each application can get only some of the messages.